# JPA: Composite Primary and Foreign Keys

Tags: java, orm, annotations, jpa-2.0, one-to-one

I have situation where I have some legacy tables.
Assets, with composite PK (assetId, fiscalId, recordType)
AssetSystems, with composite PK (assetId, fiscalId, systemId)

And they have a relationship.
Asset 1 - 1 AssetSystems
where, Systems FK (assetId, fiscalId)

Here's my code.

Asset.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Assets")
public class Asset implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private AssetKey compositeKey;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="asset")
private AssetSystem assetSystem;

    // other fields and setters - getters

}
```

AssetKey.java

```
@Embeddable
public class AssetKey implements java.io.Serializable {

@Column(name="assetID")
private String assetID;

@Column(name="fiscalPeriodID")
private BigInteger fiscalPeriodID;

@Column(name="recordType")
private String recordType;

// setter - getter
```

}

AssetSystem.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AssetSystems")
public class AssetSystem implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private AssetSystemKey compositeKey;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns({
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="assetID", referencedColumnName="assetID"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="fiscalPeriodID", referencedColumnName="fiscalPeriodID")
})
private Asset asset;

// other fields and setter - getter

}
```

AssetSystemKey.java

```
@Embeddable
public class AssetSystemKey implements Serializable {

@Column(name="assetID")
private String assetID;

@Column(name="fiscalPeriodID")
private BigInteger fiscalPeriodID;

@Column(name="systemID")
private BigInteger systemID;

// setter - getter
}
```

When I try to access the DB, I get this exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for
>   class com.wb.adapter.model.AssetSystem. Expected: class
>   com.wb.adapter.model.AssetSystemKey, got class
>   com.wb.adapter.model.AssetKey     at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:274)     at
>   com.wb.adapter.main.AssetDbReader.readDB(AssetDbReader.java:47)   at
>   com.wb.adapter.main.AssetDbReader.main(AssetDbReader.java:30) Caused
>   by: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type
>   for class com.wb.adapter.model.AssetSystem. Expected: class
>   com.wb.adapter.model.AssetSystemKey, got class
>   com.wb.adapter.model.AssetKey

I have also tried replacing the **PrimaryKeyJoinColumns** with simple **JoinColumn** which results in this exception.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException:
>   referencedColumnNames(assetID, fiscalPeriodID) of
>   com.wb.adapter.model.AssetSystem.asset referencing
>   com.wb.adapter.model.Asset not mapped to a single property

I am new to JPA and not sure what am I doing wrong. Also, is there a better way to model the above mentioned tables in JPA, which will in effect resolve this issue.

Many thanks in advance.

Sahil

Comment: have you discovered what's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace @PrimaryKeyJoinColumns with @JoinColumns and add @MapsId("compositeKey") for Asset reference.

Comment: This gives - The type of the ID mapped by the relationship 'asset' does not agree with the primary key class of the target entity.